# Moving longtable left of margin

Tags: longtable

I am trying to create a table with a list for firms. However, due to the length of the firm names, it becomes a bit too wide. I have set a fixed width to the columns, but I would still like to move the table a bit to the left of the margin.
I am aware that it is not best practice to do so, but as I am already using a very small text size, I would prefer it anyway.

I have tried several of the solutions proposed in similar question, such as adding \hspace*{-4cm} or \hskip-4.0cm, etc. without any luck.

Here is the code I am using:

Any clever ideas?

```
\begingroup
\tiny
{\RaggedRight
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{longtable}{p{1.6cm}p{3.1cm}p{3.1cm}p{0.1cm}p{1.6cm}p{3.1cm}p{3.1cm}}
\textbf{Event Date} & \textbf{Acquirer Name} & \textbf{Target Name} &  & \textbf{Event Date} & \textbf{Acquirer Name} & \textbf{Target Name} \\
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
01/01/1999 & THALES SA & ADI LTD &  & 01/01/1999 & TRAVIS PERKINS PLC & KEYLINE BUILDERS MERCHANTS LTD \\
02/02/1999 & OBRASCON HUARTE LAIN SA & CONSTRUCCIONES LAIN SA &  & 04/02/1999 & ADECCO SA & DELPHI GROUP PLC \\
23/02/1999 & RWE AG & VEW AG &  & 01/03/1999 & SAGE GROUP PLC, THE & TETRA PLC \\
11/03/1999 & PENAUILLE POLY SERVICES SA & SERVISAIR PLC &  & 22/03/1999 & VIVENDI SA (OLD) & US FILTER CORPORATION \\
30/03/1999 & ENTERPRISE INNS PLC & CENTURY INNS PLC &  & 01/04/1999 & BP AMOCO PLC & ATLANTIC RICHFIELD COMPANY \\
12/04/1999 & CSM NV & LEAF OY &  & 14/04/1999 & IMI PLC & POLYPIPE LTD \\
23/04/1999 & GECINA SA & SEFIMEG - SOCIETE FRANCAISE D'INVESTISSEMENTS IMMOBILIERS ET DE GESTION &  & 19/05/1999 & BRITISH AMERICAN TOBACCO PLC & ROTHMANS HOLDINGS LTD \\
08/06/1999 & ELECTROCOMPONENTS PLC & ALLIED ELECTRONICS INC. &  & 14/06/1999 & STAGECOACH HOLDINGS PLC & COACH USA INC. \\
22/06/1999 & GREENE KING PLC & MORLAND PLC &  & 06/07/1999 & WOLTERS KLUWER NV & BANKERS SYSTEMS INC. \\
30/07/1999 & TRINITY PLC & MIRROR GROUP PLC &  & 30/08/1999 & CARREFOUR SA & PROMODES SA \\
25/10/1999 & TRAVIS PERKINS PLC & SHARPE \& FISHER PLC &  & 01/11/1999 & MORGAN CRUCIBLE COMPANY PLC, THE & VACUUMSCHMELZE GMBH \& CO KG \\
16/11/1999 & SAAB AB & CELSIUS AB &  & 22/11/1999 & WHITBREAD PLC & SWALLOW GROUP PLC \\
03/01/2000 & HUFVUDSTADEN AB & VASATERMINALEN AB &  & 11/01/2000 & PUBLICIS GROUPE SA & FRANKEL \& COMPANY \\
12/01/2000 & SAGE GROUP PLC, THE & BEST SOFTWARE INC. &  & 14/01/2000 & TELEFONICA SA & TELEFONICA DEL PERU SAA \\
18/02/2000 & RADIOTRONICA SA & TELEVISION Y SONIDO TELSON SA &  & 28/02/2000 & MERKANTILDATA ASA & AVENIR ASA \\
07/03/2000 & KONINKLIJKE AHOLD NV & US FOODSERVICE INC. &  & 10/03/2000 & PEARSON PLC & DORLING KINDERSLEY HOLDINGS LTD \\
14/03/2000 & BP AMOCO PLC & BURMAH CASTROL PLC &  & 15/03/2000 & SBS BROADCASTING SA & STRATEUROP INTERNATIONAL BV \\
22/03/2000 & ABENGOA SA & BEFESA MEDIO AMBIENTE SA &  & 24/03/2000 & RENAULT SA & BENETTON FORMULA LTD \\
03/04/2000 & NH HOTELES SA & KRASNAPOLSKY HOTELS \& RESTAURANTS NV &  & 05/04/2000 & PIERRE ET VACANCES SA & GRAN DORADO LEISURE NV \\
06/04/2000 & COMPAGNIE DE SAINT-GOBAIN SA & RAAB KARCHER BAUSTOFFE GMBH &  & 12/04/2000 & CAPITA GROUP PLC, THE & IRG PLC
\end{longtable}
}
\end{adjustwidth}
\endgroup
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reset the length \LTleft:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

some text\\some text

\setlength\LTleft{-2cm}
\begin{longtable}{l}
xxxxxxx
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, worked like a charm! Thanks!